# Warning: Undefined Array Key "Edit" In C:\Xampp\Htdocs\Proyecto Final 2\Crud2\Admin_update.Php On Line 5

Tags: php, html, css

estoy teniendo el siguiente error:
Warning: Undefined Array Key "Edit" In C:\Xampp\Htdocs\Proyecto Final 2\Crud2\Admin_update.Php On Line 5

La verdad es que creo que el error es una tontera pero no logro encontrarlo.
Este es el código donde salta el error:

```
@include 'config.php';

$id = $_GET['edit'];

if(isset($_POST['update_personal'])){

   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $salary = $_POST['salary'];
   $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
   $image_folder = 'uploaded_img/'.$image;

   if(empty($name) || empty($salary) || empty($image)){
      $message[] = 'Por favor, rellena todos los campos';    
   }else{

      $update_data = "UPDATE empleados SET name='$name', salary='$salary', image='$image'  WHERE id = '$id'";
      $upload = mysqli_query($conn, $update_data);

      if($upload){
         move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, $image_folder);
         header('location:admin_page.php');
      }else{
         $$message[] = 'Por favor, rellena todos los campos'; 
      }

   }
};

?>
```

Y ese código debería ejecutarse al clickear aquí:

```
<a href="admin_update.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn"> <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>edit </a>
```

Comment: No entiendo que el error te de esto: `Undefined Array Key "Edit" ` en cambio en el código que nos muestras `edit` lo tienes en minúsculas tanto en el enlace como en el GET.  ¿seguro que es lo mismo aquí y en tu código?

Answer (score 0):

consulta veo que estas usando get y post. Estas enviando los datos por javascript o alguna función? Pregunto porque los hipervínculos normalmente no envían datos post. (pregunto porque no conozco tu código) y asegúrate que ese edit está siendo enviado con el número id. Por temas de seguridad siempre asegúrate con un if que el valor está siendo recibido (isset !empty)